# create blank underline in XMLWorker itext

Tags: itext, pdf-conversion

I Have a field and a blank underlined space to put the value on(like Field_Name ***_*____**). I am doing it on a pdf converted from html using XMLWorker of itext. All I have in mind is create an inline empty div (beside the field) and give it a border-bottom. but border-bottom isn't being displayed. anyone got a better working idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Border-bottom doesn't work on a  element. It does work on cells.

Source: http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/CSS-conformance-list.htm

Comment: So I think most of the elements have to be in table tags.

Comment: It is considerably easier using tables, yes.